# trying to remove color: inherit; property in React

Tags: css, reactjs, styles

not an expert React user here. I have some links hidden (color and hover). I tried to fix it in my css but this always happens:

[hidden links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLxX5.png)

The only way that I found to avoid this is removing `color: inherit;` manually. Is there any option to remove it when my DApp is launched? I can't find this action on Internet.

[my solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fw7M8.png)

The CSS of those link components are:

```
export const NavLinks = styled(LinkS)`
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;

    &:hover {
        color: #01bf71;
        border-bottom: 3px solid #01bf71;
    }

    &.active {
        border-bottom: 3px solid #01bf71;
    }
`;
```

Comment: Please add your code as actual code instead of images.

Comment: @FabianSchöner sorry, I missed it. My problem is... I have many files, and that affects to a couple of components. Specifically, my Navbar and its components are in `src/components/navbar` folder. I have a sandbox of my project: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/Joncarre/React-DApp